# LINQ to Entities. How to create "Reusable" methods that "wrap" entities?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

**SETUP**
I have an "Order" class and an "OrderDetail" class.
The Order class has a property called "OrderDetails" of type IQueryable.
I have a method in each class called "GetData" and this method returns IQueryable of the class it is in.
The "GetData" methods are wrappers around the Entities that are used to transform the Entities into friendlier .NET classes / properties.
For example: The OrderDetail Entity has a "PullDate" in the database as Char(10) but I want the OrderDetail Class to have a property called "PullDate" that is of type DateTime in the class.

**CODE**

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }

    public static IQueryable<Order> GetData()
    {
        IQueryable<Order> orders;
        var db = new OrderEntities();

        // NOTE: This code will work
        try
        {
            var data = 
                (from O in db.Orders
                 where O.OrderID == 1
                 select new Order
                 {
                     ID = O.OrderID,
                     OrderDetails = 
                         (from OD in db.OrderDetails
                          where OD.OrderID == O.OrderID
                          select new OrderDetail
                          {
                              ID = OD.OrderDetailID,
                              OrderID = OD.OrderID,
                              PullDate = OD.PullDate == "00000000" ?
                                  (DateTime?)null : db.yyyyMMddToDate(OD.PullDate),
                              Description = OD.Desc
                          })
                 });

            orders = data.AsQueryable();
            var orderList = orders.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            throw;
        }

        // NOTE: This code will NOT work
        try
        {
            var data = (from O in db.Orders
                        where O.OrderID == 1
                        select new Order
                        {
                            ID = O.OrderID,
                            OrderDetails = (from OD in OrderDetail.GetData(db)
                                            where OD.OrderID == O.OrderID
                                            select OD)
                        });

            orders = data.AsQueryable();
            var orderList = orders.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }

        return orders;
    }
}


public class OrderDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PullDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public static IQueryable<OrderDetail> GetData(OrderEntities db)
    {
        IQueryable<OrderDetail> orderDetails;

            var data = (from OD in db.OrderDetails
                        select new OrderDetail
                        {
                            ID = OD.OrderDetailID,
                            OrderID = OD.OrderID,
                            PullDate = OD.PullDate == "00000000" ?
                                (DateTime?)null : db.yyyyMMddToDate(OD.PullDate),
                            Description = OD.Desc
                        });

            orderDetails = data.AsQueryable();
            var orderList = orderDetails.ToList();

            return orderDetails;
    }
}
```

**ERROR**
    LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Models.OrderDetail] GetData(Models.OrderEntities)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

**Request**
I would like the Order.GetData method to call the OrderDetail.GetData method using LINQ.
I need to "join" the GetData methods together or "sub select" the OrderDetail.GetData while inside the Order.GetData class.
Both of the classes are querying EntityFramework inside of their GetData methods.
Projection is a requirement.
My goal is to create "Reusable" methods like "GetData" in my DTO classes that will contain specific SQL / Entity logic.
For example, I am using a lot of custom SQL functions like "db.yyyyMMddToDate" in my DTO classes to transform the Entities into something more object / .NET friendly and I don't want to "retype" all that logic each time I need to "join / sub select" data from entities.

In LINQ to Objects this would be the same as joining two different lists from different classes.
But it seems that LINQ to Entity does not know how to join methods from other classes even if the method is marked as Queryable.
I understand that LINQ to Entity is treating the "GetData" methods as if they were SQL functions but I need a way to tell LINQ to Entity that these are just more Entities to join together to get the results.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because, when dealing with LINQ to Entities, you are not passing in lambdas to the LINQ operators like you do in LINQ to Object. You are passing expression trees. The code that you write in those queries will never be executed. It will be interpreted by Entity Framework as a series of instruction to translate into an other language like SQL.

The `GetData` method doesn't mean anything in SQL. In fact, it doesn't mean anything outside of your own program. This is why LINQ to Entities do not recognize your method as a valid construct.

To access the details of an order in a scenario like yours, you need to build your query so that EF knows to include the OrderDetails entities inside the primary query using the Include operator. When doing this, EF expects your object to have a property similar to this one:

```
public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
```

This is how EF will know where to put the resulting objects from queries that includes those elements.

```
var ctx = new DatabaseContext();
var query = ctx.Orders
   .Where(o => o.OrderId == 1)
   .Include(o => o.OrderDetails);
```

This query will asks the remote server for all Orders, with an OrderId of 1, with all its matching OrderDetails. EF will then automatically create all of the related client side entities for you.

Here's the official documentation on EF about this topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: How is the "include" any different than using the sub-select I have in example (1) labeled as "This code will work"?  My example is simplifying the problem I am having but in general I need to be able to call the OrderDetail.GetData so that way LINQ can call the database once for the entire LINQ expression.

Comment: The Include method tells EF to generate a join clause inside the  underlying query. This will automatically populate the virtual ICollection<OrderDetails> property named OrderDetails that you should have in your Orders object. What you are currently trying to do is to tell EF to generate a call to `GetData` within the query. This is a SQL query, it is not executed within the context of your application. It is executed on a potentially remote server which has absolutely no idea what `GetData` means. Thus, EF cannot translate the `GetData` call into anything meaningful.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how the "Include" is going to help me call OrderDetails.GetData? All the "Include" is going to do is tell LINQ to "include" data from the OrderDetails entity. Using the "Include" in this case is no different than using a "join" in the LINQ Expression I already have working in example 1. The "Include" would also not allow me to project the Entity into the DTO object.

Comment: Actually, because of the include clause, EF will automatically fills the navigation property I mentioned for you, so you do not even have to project the OrderDetails into Order yourself. This is the basis of how relations are handled with EF. You are not supposed to try to do this on your own with a custom GetData method. Include is there to do exactly that for you.

Comment: I have to use projection. For example the "Order" class has a property called "ID" but the "Order" entity does not have ID instead it has a field called "OrderID" that maps to "ID" in the Order class. My example was very bland. In the real environment, there isn't even an Entity called "Order" but several Entities are joined together in my "Order" class to form a Order model. I will add more information to the question to better help explain the problem.

Comment: The fields names does not have to match. EF can take care of this for you too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/jj591583.aspx

Also, EF can take care of relational inheritance for you too which should take care of joining together multiples tables inside a single model: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Really, I fail to see why you would absolutely need to use projection. If it can be written in a single SQL query, then there is no need to use projection.

Comment: Without adding too much more onto this discussion. The database is not designed as "Entity" friendly. For example: Date fields in the database are stored as Char, there is little-to-no primary keys, absolutely no foreign keys, the list goes on... Let's assume projection is a requirement. Since the Entities are no good, I am using a DTO style to make the data look good at the business layer.

Comment: In that case, you have to make the call through LINQ to Object. It is not possible to do this projection though LINQ to Entities.